# Change the format of a google spreadsheet date to include day of the week

Tags: date, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I am trying to change a simple date format "1/24/2016" to " Tuesday, Jan 24 2016"

```
sheet.getRange("A2:A10").setNumberFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy");
```

prints:

```
"EEE, Jan 24 2016"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an undocumented feature 
you can use:

```
range.setNumberFormat("DDD, MMM dd, YYYY");
```

For more details you can see the issue report here:

https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=setNumberFormat&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner&groupby=&sort=&id=4175

Comment: To add, you can find `setNumberFormat` in the documentation for [Range Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnumberformatnumberformat).